# What is the SQLite query to extract data from one column if a BOOL column is set to 'true'?

Tags: sqlite

The following query works for me (in SQLite) for a simple search in the database.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    slovník
WHERE   Note like '%); "%'
```

What if I want to do the same search but want to filter the results further like this:

[please see the screenshot][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `Phrase` in your table stores integer values `0` or `1` which are the values that SQLite considers as *Boolean*.
In your case any of the below statements will work:

```
WHERE Note like '%); "%' AND Phrase
```

or

```
WHERE Note like '%); "%' AND Phrase = true
```

or

```
WHERE Note like '%); "%' AND Phrase = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[2.1. Boolean Datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

So your query would look like the following, to select rows where the phrase is true:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    slovník
WHERE   Phrase = 1
  AND   Note like '%); "%';
```

Comment: Thank you, that works but if I add:
WHERE   Note like '%); "%'
I get an error. You see, I'd like to get items from the Note column that are checked in Phrases (Phrase = 1). Hope it makes sense, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Apparently, we can now also use `Phrase IS TRUE`, which to some degree also takes care of NULL values.

Comment: @JosefH. you have to join multiple conditions with `AND`, I updated my answer. But if you are missing such basics it makes more sense to read a basic tutorial on SQL first.